# Centralized logging over intermittent connection

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I'm using `rsyslog` to forward syslog entries from a pile of servers to [Loggly](http://loggly.com)

The configuration looks something like this:

```
# Config for loggly upload
*.* @@logs.loggly.com:12345
```

This works, but because it's forwarding, any log entries which occur when there isn't an internet connection never make it to loggly.

Is there anyway I can configure rsyslog to "hold" log entries until an internet connection is established, and then send them? Or is there another tool I should be using for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rsyslog is able to buffer messages to disk if it is unable to contact a remote server.  The default  `rsyslog.conf` on my Fedora system includes the following example:

```
# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog # where to place spool files
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
# 
### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

The configuration is explain detail in [this document](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_reliable_forwarding.html).

Comment: Dang. You beat me as I was just typing all that out since I couldn't copy/paste it. :)

Answer (score 1):

**syslog-ng** can buffer logs to disk if it can't send them to the server.

```
 destination d_tcp { tcp(“logserver” log_disk_fifo_size(100000000)); };
```